# Override Tomcat connectionTimeout property

Tags: jsf, tomcat

Is there a posibility to Override Tomcat7 connectionTimeout property already stored in /tomcat/conf/server.xml. I mean setting a property in my application-context.xml file like

```
<bean id="dataSourceC3p0" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass"  value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
    <property name="maxStatements" value="0" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
    <property name="numHelperThreads" value="5"/>
    <property name="connectionTimeout" value="200000"/>
</bean>
```

although, last line is throwing an error:

```
org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'connectionTimeout'
```

all other properties are ok when I just comment last property

NotWritablePropertyException just tells me that there's no other way to set this value right ?

Thanks in Advanced

Comment: you could create a method or something in a masterpage if you are using it so that everytime a postback is triggered you can increment the timeout property and assign it to a static variable are you wanting Connection Timeout or Command Timeout..?

Comment: I want to use another value to ConnectionTimeout value stored in server.xml, so I can use different values for each application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Property name is wrong..

Look at this doc:
http://www.databaseskill.com/4369778/

```
 <! - When the connection pool is used when the client calls the getConnection () 
 waiting to acquire a new connection timeout before throwing
 SQLException, if set to 0 wait indefinitely. Milliseconds. Default: 0 ->

 <property name="checkoutTimeout"> 100 </ property>
```

Hope that helps